# Designing for all resolution

Tags: android

My layout structure is as below:

res/layout-small-ldpi
res/layout-ldpi
res/layout-mdpi
res/layout-large-mdpi
res/layout-hdpi.

I have the images for the following resolution:

240x320
320x480
480x800
1024x600

but i don't know where to place these images in drawables. Please help.

Comment: The android documentation provides guidance regarding supporting multiple screen sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four types of Drawable folder in your res named folder so you have to put.

```
1) for 240x320 image put it to in drawable-ldpi or simple drawable folder.
2) for 320x480 image put it to in drawable-mdpi 
3) for 480x800 image put it to in drawable-hdpi 
4) for 1024x600image put it to in drawable-xhdpi.
```

Comment: In all other screens it's working properly but in 1024x600 resolution, it's not working properly. I added the images in the drawables just like u suggested. In 1024x600 it's taking small image icons.

Comment: try to create new folder named "drawable-xxhdpi" in res folder and put all 1024*600 images in that.

Comment: I tried but same result.I'm running this application on samsung tab 1024x600 resolution. The icons displayed are very small.

Comment: the problem is because you didn't create a res/layout-xlarge folder.. Crate it and now put images in drawable-xhdpi folder and get a better solution.

Comment: I did that too but same result. The tablet is 7" tablet.